# Transitions in D3 Axis

Tags: d3.js

I'm trying to create a grouped bar chart that can include transitions. I referenced Mike Bostock's grouped bar chart  example and have the bar chart transition working but can't get the axis to transition as well. What I'm referring to in this example is the state labels.

I tried following another example posted but I'm baffled as to why I can get it to work. For my example code the transition occurs on click of the SVG

Grouped Bar Chart Reference [Example](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3887051)

Axis Reference [Example](http://bl.ocks.org/phoebebright/3098488)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>

body {
  font: 10px sans-serif;
}

.axis path,
.axis line {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #000;
  shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}

.bar {
  fill: steelblue;
}

.x_axis path {
  display: none;
}

</style>
<body>
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
<script>

//Update the flips bars but not the axis
function update() {
    var data_update = data.reverse()

    x0.domain[data_update]

      svg.selectAll(".state")
      .data(data_update)
      .transition()
      .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + x0(d.State) + ",0)"; });

      svg.select(".x_axis")
      .transition()
      .call(xAxis);
    }

d3.select("svg")
    .on("click", update)

//The rest of the code
var data

var margin = {top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 40},
    width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var x0 = d3.scale.ordinal()
    .rangeRoundBands([0, width], .1);

var x1 = d3.scale.ordinal();

var y = d3.scale.linear()
    .range([height, 0]);

var color = d3.scale.ordinal()
    .range(["#98abc5", "#8a89a6", "#7b6888", "#6b486b", "#a05d56", "#d0743c", "#ff8c00"]);

var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(x0)
    .orient("bottom");

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

d3.csv("data.csv", function(error, csv) {
  data = csv
  var ageNames = d3.keys(data[0]).filter(function(key) { return key !== "State"; });

  data.forEach(function(d) {
    d.ages = ageNames.map(function(name) { return {name: name, value: +d[name]}; });
  });

  x0.domain(data.map(function(d) { return d.State; }));
  x1.domain(ageNames).rangeRoundBands([0, x0.rangeBand()]);
  y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d3.max(d.ages, function(d) { return d.value; }); })]);

  svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "x_axis")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
      .call(xAxis);


  var state = svg.selectAll(".state")
      .data(data)
    .enter().append("g")
      .attr("class", "state")
      .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + x0(d.State) + ",0)"; });


  state.selectAll("rect")
      .data(function(d) { return d.ages; })
    .enter().append("rect")
      .attr("width", x1.rangeBand())
      .attr("x", function(d) { return x1(d.name); })
      .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.value); })
      .attr("height", function(d) { return height - y(d.value); })
      .style("fill", function(d) { return color(d.name); });

});

</script>
```

Comment: Your question is not very clear. What is it exactly that you want to transition? Also, the gist you provided is 404'd.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm a dummy and figured it out.

Calling the .domain method on an array of objects is useless. I forgot to map the object array to get the value of the states

```
x0.domain(data_update.map(function(d) { return d.State; }))
```

Full Code below for those curious

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>

body {
  font: 10px sans-serif;
}

.axis path,
.axis line {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #000;
  shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}

.bar {
  fill: steelblue;
}

.x_axis path {
  display: none;
}

</style>
<body>
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
<script>

var data

var margin = {top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 40},
    width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var x0 = d3.scale.ordinal()
    .rangeRoundBands([0, width], .1);

var x1 = d3.scale.ordinal();

var y = d3.scale.linear()
    .range([height, 0]);

var color = d3.scale.ordinal()
    .range(["#98abc5", "#8a89a6", "#7b6888", "#6b486b", "#a05d56", "#d0743c", "#ff8c00"]);

var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(x0)
    .orient("bottom");

var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(y)
    .orient("left")
    .tickFormat(d3.format(".2s"));

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

d3.csv("data.csv", function(error, csv) {
  data = csv
  var ageNames = d3.keys(data[0]).filter(function(key) { return key !== "State"; });

  data.forEach(function(d) {
    d.ages = ageNames.map(function(name) { return {name: name, value: +d[name]}; });
  });

  x0.domain(data.map(function(d) { return d.State; }));
  x1.domain(ageNames).rangeRoundBands([0, x0.rangeBand()]);
  y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d3.max(d.ages, function(d) { return d.value; }); })]);

  svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "x_axis")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
      .call(xAxis);

  svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "y axis")
      .call(yAxis)
    .append("text")
      .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
      .attr("y", 6)
      .attr("dy", ".71em")
      .style("text-anchor", "end")
      .text("Population");

  var state = svg.selectAll(".state")
      .data(data, function(d) {return d.State})
    .enter().append("g")
      .attr("class", "state")
      .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + x0(d.State) + ",0)"; });


  state.selectAll("rect")
      .data(function(d) { return d.ages; })
    .enter().append("rect")
      .attr("width", x1.rangeBand())
      .attr("x", function(d) { return x1(d.name); })
      .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.value); })
      .attr("height", function(d) { return height - y(d.value); })
      .style("fill", function(d) { return color(d.name); });

  var legend = svg.selectAll(".legend")
      .data(ageNames.slice().reverse())
    .enter().append("g")
      .attr("class", "legend")
      .attr("transform", function(d, i) { return "translate(0," + i * 20 + ")"; });

  legend.append("rect")
      .attr("x", width - 18)
      .attr("width", 18)
      .attr("height", 18)
      .style("fill", color);

  legend.append("text")
      .attr("x", width - 24)
      .attr("y", 9)
      .attr("dy", ".35em")
      .style("text-anchor", "end")
      .text(function(d) { return d; });

});

//Update the flips bars
function update() {

    data.reverse()
    x0.domain(data.map(function(d) { return d.State; }))

      svg.selectAll(".state")
      .data(data, function(d) {return d.State})
      .transition()
      .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + x0(d.State) + ",0)"; });

      svg.select(".x_axis")
      .transition()
      .call(xAxis);
    }

d3.select("svg")
    .on("click", update)



</script>
```